# MCP23017 I2C Device driver probe function is not called

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am using the following I2C/GPIO [Device driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpio/gpio-mcp23s08.c) to access the MCP23017 GPIOs. With the insmod command I am able to load the driver and its listed in /proc/modules. I have two MCP23017 chips connected to my Raspberry Pi. Both are detected at addresses `0x20` and `0x21`. The initcall to the driver registers the driver. I checked this by printing out a message. But the driver probe function is not called. The devices are not opened/ cannot be located elsewhere.

1. How is the probe function called?
2. Should the probe be done manually to locate the devices?
3. Is the `probe` call similar to the `open` call?
4. I tried this  `echo mcp23017 0x20 > new_device` to manually create a new device with the address. But it didnt work. I got the followin message: `Driver 'mcp23s08' is already registered, aborting...`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can I find device tree file you are using for your board?

Comment: I am quite new to Linux. Do you want me to post the device tree file here? Sorry, I did not understand your question.

Comment: Your device (MCP23017) has to be described in device tree. So either the device tree file for your board should have this description, or you should create your own device tree overlay for your device and load it along with driver. Without proper device description in device tree, your driver `probe()` function won't be called, as this function is only called when driver is matched with device tree description. So I'm asking you to provide the link to your device tree file (that you are using for your board) or provide your device tree overlay for your device (that you load before driver).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I found the `mcp23017.dtbo` file which I suppose is the device tree overlay for the device. If this is the right device overlay how do I load it to the driver?

Comment: This is the link to the [overlay file](http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/rpi-firmware/boot/overlays/)

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`probe()` function is called when driver is matched with your device description in Device Tree. Matching happens when [compatible](http://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage#Understanding_the_compatible_Property) field of your driver found in Device Tree (for your driver it's `"microchip,mcp23017"` string).

Apparently you don't have your device (MCP23017) described in Device Tree, that's why `probe()` is not called. You can load corresponding Device Tree Overlay to overcome this issue. The [one](http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/rpi-firmware/boot/overlays/mcp23017.dtbo) you pointed out in your comment seems to be correct. Read more about loading overlays in Raspberry Pi ecosystem [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md).

You can try to load your overlay like described in that article:

```
$ sudo dtoverlay mcp23017.dtbo
```

Or you can try to use [Capemgr](http://elinux.org/Capemgr) for this purpose. Personally I didn't try any of those, so you should look which works for you best.

### Update

Replying to your questions in comments.

> But when I try the `i2cdetect` command it shows UU.

See [man i2cdetect](http://linux.die.net/man/8/i2cdetect). So "UU" means that `i2cdetect` skipped probing because device at the address you specified is already used by driver. I guess it what you intended, so it's ok.

> With a `rmmod mcp23017` command I see the device still under devices but `i2cdetect` shows `0x20`

So you unloaded the driver and now `i2cdetect` shows you that there is some device on `0x20` address. I guess it's correct behavior. Also if you want to get rid completely of your device -- try to unload DT overlay along with driver.

> Also I have connected two MCP23017 chips. But I can see only the device at `0x20` under devices. The I2C chip at `0x21` is still not detected, though the driver says it supports up to 8 chips

I can see two possible causes to this issue.

1. DT overlay only has description for device with `0x20` address, but missing description for device with `0x21` address. If this is the case, you should find sources for your DT overlay, add description for rest of your devices, compile that modified DT overlay and then load it instead of pre-built one.
2. All devices may be configured for using `0x20` address. See section `1.4
   Hardware Address Decoder` in [MCP23017](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/mcp23017.pdf) datasheet for details. Check `A0`, `A1`, `A2` pins on your chips.

Comment: Thank you. The probe function worked. The mcp23017 is detected and I can find it under `/sys/bus/i2c/devices` as 1-0020 and it has a name `mcp23017`. But when I try the `i2cdetect` command it shows UU. With a `rmmod mcp23017` command I see the device still under devices but i2cdetect shows `0x20`. Any idea what is the problem here? Also I have connected two MCP23017 chips. But I can see only the device at 0x20 under devices. The I2C chip at 0x21 is still not detected, though the driver says it supports upto 8 chips

Comment: First of all, it would be interesting to know what is the procedure you used to load DT overlay and driver? As for your questions, -- I'll try to address them a bit later.

Comment: I followed the article you mentioned (and the command) to load the DT overlay. And `insmod` to load the driver.

Comment: I replied to your questions in **Update** section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified the overlay and it works. Now I am trying to use the GPIO pins and interrupts. But, with the driver and overlay loaded(i.e. when UU is displayed), I am unable to set the gpio pins using `i2cget` and `i2cset` commands. I get an `Error: Could not set address to 0x20: Device or resource busy`.

Comment: I have same problem where `i2cdetect` shows `UU`. when I run `rmmod mcp23017` shows `rmmod: ERROR: Module mcp23017 is not currently loaded`. any idea?